# get particular child view in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

using getChildAt() we can get the view of particular row in list view. Likewise can we get the particular child view in expandable list view ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
String mChildValue = tv.getText().toString();

}
```